# click event of submit button executes first before controllers method returns the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing MVC application.

I have user form in which user supposed to add his/her details with username and password.

I check duplication of username when user fills the entire form and clicks on save button.

I have written this duplication checking logic in controller and I call this method from view, when user click on submit button. (in controller's method, if username exist it returns true otherwise false.)

Method works fine, but the problem is when cursor goes to controller method, mean while data gets saved. ( though I have used preventDefault() )

**Cursor don't wait for the methods return value in view.  i.e. true or false.**

It supposed to check the return value and behave accordingly.

How to solve it ?

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) 
    {
        var uName = $('#EditUserName').val();
        var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CheckDuplicateUserName", "Employee", new {@Id=Model.Id, @UserName = "userName"}))";
         url = url.replace("userName", uName);
         url = url.replace("Id", '@ViewBag.Employee.Id');
        $.post(url, function (data)
        {
            if (data == true) 
            {

                $('#EditduplicateUserName').text("UserName already exist,please try some other username.");
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $('#EditduplicateUserName').text("");
            }

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call preventDefault within the ajax success function because the ajax is asyncronous and your `click` event will have along completed, before the ajax success event fires (when the response is received).

The solution is to always preventDefault in the click event, then programatically submit the form if the username is not taken, in the success function.

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // always prevent default

    var uName = $('#EditUserName').val();
    var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CheckDuplicateUserName", "Employee", new {@Id=Model.Id, @UserName = "userName"}))";

    url = url.replace("userName", uName);
    url = url.replace("Id", '@ViewBag.Employee.Id');
    $.post(url, function (data) {
        if (data == true) {

            $('#EditduplicateUserName').text("UserName already exist,please try some other username.");
        } else {
            $('#EditduplicateUserName').text("");
            $('#yourform')[0].submit(); // submit the form
        }

    });
});
```

Side note: the form's `onsubmit` event is preferred to the submit button's `click` event, because the former fires in other scenarios such as submission via the enter key, whereas the latter doesn't.